# Vim: how to visual select up to characters with backspaces in

Tags: vim

I have a *.qif file (text file) in which I would like to remove all lines from the second line (not including the header) to a line which contains the characters 'D1/7/2015'. In vim I have tried block selecting from the second line and searching up to a the characters but it doesn't work. What I have tried so far:

Move the cursor to second line then:

```
v/D1/7/2015
v/D1//7//2015
v/D1///7///2015
```

None of these seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape slashes with backslashes:

```
v/D1\/7\/2015
```

or tell Vim to parse your pattern with "verymagic" syntax:

```
v/\vD1/7/2015
```

See `:help \v`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what I wanted but it works. I used `/D1.7.2015` to get to the line then started visual selection up to the beginning of the file with `vgg` after which I moved one line down with the cursor then pressed `d`.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete directly without using the visual selection from the second line to the line containing  'D1/7/2015' by executing the command below:

```
:2,/D1\/7\/2015/ d
```